# Symbolic integration of vector norm

Tags: integration, plane-curves, symbolic-computation

I'd like to symbolically integrate the expression $\int_0^1{\|r'\left(t\right)\|_2\,dt}$ where $r$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ (so the expression is the arc length of the curve $r$). It'd be nice if this would work for any function that can be integrated and differentiated, but I'd already be pretty happy if it worked for polynomials.

Expanding the definition of the Euclidean norm yields

$$\int_0^1{\sqrt{\left(r'_1\left(t\right)\right)^2+\left(r'_2\left(t\right)\right)^2}\,dt}$$

where $r'_1$ and $r'_2$ denote the component functions of $r'$. I've done some research and it seems that there is no general solution for the integral of a square root of an arbitrary polynomial, but maybe the special form of this one makes it possible? Unfortunately, it doesn't look like any of the popular integration identities applies here.

If it turns out to be impossible, I'll be able to use numerical integration, but since I want to use this expression in a smooth nonlinear optimization problem, it'd be a lot easier if there was a symbolic solution to this integration, so I'd be very grateful for any pointers on how to do this, if it is possible.

Comment: Your notation is confusing.  I'm not saying it's necessarily wrong, but if you want to communicate with people, you should use more standard and less confusing notation.  Since $f$ is vector-valued, most people would write something like $\mathbf{r}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and call the independent variable $t$.  Then you compute $\int_0^1 \|\mathbf{r}'(t)\|\,dt$.  Since $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is vector-valued, $\|\mathbf{r}'(t)\|$ will involve a square root.  Whether or not you can do the integral in closed form depends on $\mathbf{r}$.  Can you give an example?

Comment: I didn't know $f$ was reserved for functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I've edited my post accordingly. I don't know much about the functions since the algorithm should be as generic as possible, but the simplest curves I'll deal with are arbitrary polynomials (at least quadratic). Their coefficients are what is optimized for, so they will always be just variables. I guess if it doesn't even work for arbitrary polynomials I'll have to give up on symbolic integration here.

Comment: Sometimes people use $f: \mathbf{R}^m \to \mathbf{R}^n$.  There are no absolute rules here, only conventions.  I think your switch in notation makes this problem a lot more readable.  I also think that whether or not you can actually do the integral depends on the degree of the polynomial and even on the actual form of the polynomial.  I am pretty sure that most of the time there will be no closed-form solution for the integral and you will have to use numerical methods. There might be a closed-form solution for quadratic polynormials.